# Possible for server to run scripts

Tags: server-side, serverside-javascript

So I realize this question is broad, as I'm looking for a place to start.

Is it possible to have a server that for example runs PHP scripts every day, or every 2 minutes?

Pretty much, I don't want to put these tasks in the users script, because I'm scared they would get run a lot more than is necessary, and I'd prefer to keep it separate.

I'm looking to keep it javascript, PHP or SQL as I don't have the time to learn a new language atm, so if any of you have any good places for me to read up on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Note that cron is for **basic** tasks. There are better systems if you need more complicated stuff.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add [cron](http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial) jobs. It allows you to schedule how often you'd like to run the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript will not run server side as you are expecting. what I would suggest is you look into writing a cron job to run a bash file.  It would take minimal research to complete.

[Cron Intro](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

[Bash Intro](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Comment: Eh, node.js will run JavaScript in the server.

Comment: And you would rather use node.js to run a file than the 10 seconds it takes to write a cron job? Have fun!

Comment: The cron job can start the node.js program, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There **might** be **some** way to run javascript on the server side, but I'd certainly stick to PHP. SQL is not a script, by the way...

You can execute your PHP scripts every `x` minutes / hours / days using cronjobs. Just google `crontab`. You need (root) access to the server though.

Comment: I've seend Nodejs around, how does it compare to cron? Also is it possible to use comet push/pull features with either cron or Nodejs?

Comment: It doesn't compare, it's a program that uses Google's V8 JavaScript interpreter. It has nothing to do with scheduling jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's completely possible. On Linux (Mac too?), you use the [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job scheduler to run your scripts.

For Windows, you can try the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). It provides similar functionality.

You can run just about any script with `cron`, but not JavaScript (unless you use it for serverside stuff).